# How to get all parents and children rows from one table in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have table with `Categories` entity which can be parent or children.

This is `Category` table structure:

- id
- parentId
- name

If category is parent it has `parentId == -1`.

Can I use one `SQLite` query for get all parents and children categories (like `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which work for different tables)

Comment: You can join a table with itself. `SELECT a.id, b.id FROM t AS a JOIN t AS b WHERE a.id=b.parentid`

Comment: @DanD. please - write as answer - it help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join a table with itself.

```
SELECT a.id, b.id 
FROM t AS a JOIN t AS b 
WHERE a.id=b.parentid
```

You need only use `AS` to alias the table so that the columns of each occurrence can be uniquely named.